# How is ContentEncoding set in HttpWebResponse Class

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebresponse

In the .net framework there's a class called HttpWebResponse and in there there is the following property:

```
public string ContentEncoding { get; }
```

If there is not setter on this property, how is it then set and where is it set?

Answer (score 0):

It is set when the server's configured encoding is used to create the response. The encoding defines how the Unicode characters are transferred into bytes[]. I am sure this is a readonly property that is a "friendly name" string representation of one of the encoding types, in particular the one the server uses to encode the text.

A couple of Encoding types are:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
System.Text.UTF32Encoding
System.Text.UTF7Encoding
System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```